# Black screen with cursor out of nowhere while using PC, can't do anything in it

Tags: display

I've looked online, but they all address the problem only on start up or after login. This doesn't happen at either of those times, instead it happens around an hour later while I'm using it.

The screen just goes black and all that's left is the cursor. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> doesn't work, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> doesn't work either, nothing works.

What could be causing this as I would like to stop it from happening every time I go on my computer.

I have a feeling it's an overheating problem because every time I restart it, the problem occurs in less time compared to the time before it.

Please let me know what information you need, I'll be more than happy to give it.

Comment: Looks like a hardware failure in the video card of your system. Might be overheating. But all in all, not sufficient information to go troubleshooting here.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your post is hard because you actually did not tell us your question. Assuming that your question is "How can I make my PC work again as fast as possible?" (instead of "What could cause such behavior"), I would like to give the following simple advice:

Don't put much time in trying to learn about possible reasons in theory. Instead,

1. Luckily, your PC runs for a while after having started. Use that time to update your O/S with all patches, and to update your graphics driver and the other hardware drivers.
2. If the problem persists, strip down your PC as much as possible. That is, remove any devices which are not essential for the PC to start up, even if you need them for your daily work - this is only for testing.

   This basically means that you should open your PC and remove / detach everything except the mouse, the keyboard, the mainboard, the HDD with the system partition, the CPU, the CPU cooler, the RAM modules, and the graphics adapter (provided you have one, i.e. graphics are not provided by the mainboard).

   Start the PC and let it run for a while. If the problem has vanished, re-add the components you have previously removed, **one by one**. Each time, let the PC run a while and see whether the problem returns. If yes, replace that component.
3. If the problem persists, replace the graphics adapter for testing. Hopefully you have a spare one, or borrow one from a friend, or buy a used one for five dollars from eBay.

   If you don't have a graphics adapter, obviously your CPU / mainboard provides the video signals. Even then, add a separate graphics adapter and connect your monitor there to see if that solves the problem.
4. If you still haven't found the culprit, remove your RAM modules except one (assuming that your modules are 4 GB at least; with less RAM, your O/S might not work properly or too slow, thrashing your disk due to excessive swapping).

   If the PC runs properly, remove the RAM module and test the next one. Repeat until you have identified the possibly defective RAM module.
5. If the problem persists, replace (for testing, i.e. using borrowed hardware or hardware from another PC you might have), in that order: Power supply, mainboard, HDD, CPU.

Please note that the order shown above is from my limited, personal experience. This will eventually take a lot of time. Therefore, you should start testing with the components which most likely cause the problem.

Because you didn't tell us anything about your hardware and software, we can't give you more specific advice.

But to stress it again, I had to solve such problems a few times, and each time it turned out that replacing components one by one was the fastest method to identify the culprit.

One exception, though: You even didn't tell us anything about your O/S, but every O/S has logs where the reason for the failure appears if you are lucky. In Windows, that would be the logs you can view in the *Event Viewer*, and in Linux it would be the kernel logs (`dmesg`) or syslog in general.